# How Does Bash Tokenize Scripts?

Tags: bash, tokenize

Coming from a C++: it always seems like magic to me that some whitespace has an effect on the validity or semantics of the script. Here's an example:

```
echo a 2 > &1
```

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

```
echo a 2 >&1
```

> a 2

```
echo a 2>&1
```

> a

```
echo a 2>& 1
```

> a

Looking at [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Syntax) didn't help much. My main problem is that it does not feel consistent; and I am in a state of confusion.

I'm trying to find out how bash tokenizes its scripts. A general description thereof to clear up any confusion would be appreciated.

Edit:
I am NOT looking for redirections specifically. They just came up as example. Other examples:

```
A="something"
A = "something"
if [$x = $y];
if [ $x = $y ];
```

Why isn't there a space necessary between ] and ;? Why does assignment require an immediate equal sign? ...

Comment: See the specification for [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) and specifically [Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) but the main thing is to think about "words".

Comment: It does not tokenise in one scan, there are several involved.  The order of the scan can be critical, and shells vary in their order.  The basic syntax goes back a long time, and pre-dates bash itself.

Look at "word splitting" in `man bash`, 

Since you are a C++ programmer you could look at the source code https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/.  In particular look at `parse.y` which is a `yylex` file.

Comment: @EtanReisner: I accidentally forgot to add the a. I tried all commands independently.

Comment: You should also see the [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) section of the bash reference manual to understand what the `&` business in those commands is as it will help you greatly understand what is going on in those commands. In every command that doesn't error above the redirection words "disappear" from the command line (they are meta-commands in a sense and not part of the command that is run).

Comment: I can't see how this is anything other than "too broad". The only possible answer is "learn the grammar".

Comment: Also, I don't know why this feels magical. `a = = 1` isn't the same as `a == 1` in C, but that's basically what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm trying to learn the grammar by learning how it's tokenized. For example, the mealy-machine equivalent of the C `==` could return to a start state when in a symbol-state of `=` after observing a `\s`. This is all around consistent in C/C++, but in bash it feels like the lexical analyser is filled with special cases.

Comment: @BourgondAries, yes, it's full of special cases. Each special case is there for a reason (even if that reason has something to do with compatibility with 70s-era Bourne, or 80s-era ksh, or 90s-era POSIX sh); learning those reasons is perhaps the best way to understand the reasoning behind the syntax... but you can't avoid learning the special cases individually.

Comment: I'd argue, by the way, that C has less syntax overall -- that is, more of what "learning C" entails is in the library calls, and less is in the syntax -- and that this is the real difference in learning curve: It's not that C's syntax is really that much cleaner/simpler, but that there's so very little of it that you've internalized it, making it invisible to you. (And to be clear, I wholeheartedly agree with that approach; while the `bash` tag is where I have the most SO credit, my true love is the LISP family).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you gave have the behavior they do for good reason.

- Redirection sources default to FD 1. Thus, `>&1` is legitimate syntax on its own -- it redirects FD 1 to FD 1 -- meaning allowing whitespace before the `>` would result in an ambiguous syntax: The parser couldn't tell if the preceding token was its own word or a redirection source.
- Nothing other than a FD number is valid under `>&`, unless you're in a very new bash which allows a variable to be dereferenced to retrieve a FD number. In any event, anything immediately following `>&` is known to be a file descriptor, so allowing optional whitespace creates no ambiguity there.
- `a = 1` is parsed as a legitimate command, not a syntax error: It runs the command `a` with the first argument `=` and the second argument `1`. Disallowing whitespace within assignments eliminates this ambiguity. Similarly, `a= foo` has a separate and distinct meaning: It exports an environment variable `a` with an empty value while running the command `foo`. Relaxing the whitespace rules would disallow both of these legitimate commands.
- `[` is a command, not special syntax known to the parser; thus, `[foo` tries to find a command (named, say, `/usr/bin/[foo`), requiring whitespace.
- `;` takes precedence in the parser as a statement separator, rather than being treated as part of a word, unless quoted or escaped. The same is true of `&` (another separator), or a newline.

The thing is, there's no single general rule which will explain all this; you need to [read and learn the language syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10). Fortunately, there's not *very much* syntax: Almost all commands are "simple commands", which follow very simple and clear rules. You're asking about, and we're explaining, some of the exceptions to that; there are other exceptions, such as `[[ ]]` in bash, but they're small enough in total that they can be learned.

---

Other suggested resources:

- http://aosabook.org/en/bash.html (The Architecture of Open Source Applications; chapter on bash)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser (Wooledge wiki high-level description of the parser -- though this focuses more on expansion rules than tokenization)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide (an introductory guide to bash syntax in general, written with more of a focus on accuracy and best practices than some competing materials).

Answer (score 3):

`2>&1` is a single operator token, so any whitespace that breaks it up will change the meaning of the command. It just happens to be a *parameterized* token, which means the shell will further tokenize it to determine what exactly the operator does. The general form is `n>&m`, where `n` is the file descriptor you are redirecting, and `m` is the descriptor you are copying to. In this case, you are saying that the standard error (2) of the command should be copied to whatever standard output (1) is currently open on.

Comment: Note that I'm trying to find out very general rules, not just piping and/or file IO. For example:  

    `A=something`
    `A = something`

Comment: @BourgondAries, the rules *aren't* that general. Redirections have their own token type, so they have their own behavior in the parser.

Comment: @BourgondAries, ...similarly, assignments have their own rules -- and they *have to*; if `A = something` were an assignment, you could never run a command with a first argument of `=`.